# Android - Draw Views Onto SupportActionBar

Tags: android, view, overlay, android-actionbar-compat

In Android, is it possible to draw some views onto an existing Support ActionBar, such as ImageViews?

Comment: you can use ActionBar.setCustomView(ImageView)

Comment: @GopalRao
ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.send));
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(image);

Is not doing anything.

Comment: before adding ImageView, set display options to ActionBar

  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sample...

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

    actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```